# How to get the download status of file in ASP.NET mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, download, httpresponse

In my mvc2 project i have a method called DownloadPDF. In that i have,

```
httpContext.Response.WriteFile(<FilePath>);
httpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I wan't to track whether the file has downloaded successfully. I referred following tutorial but it doesn't work when i host the project in IIS.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74654/File-Download-in-ASP-NET-and-Tracking-the-Status-o

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work".  Are you getting a specific error of any sort?

Comment: It works when i debug the project in Visual studio development server. But in IIS i couldn't even download the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you application targeted for HTML 5 browser means, try the "Html5 Progress Event". It will supply all the necessary information

1. total - Total bytes being transferred
2. loaded - Bytes uploaded thus far
3. lengthComputable - Specifies if the total size of the data/file
   being uploaded is known

For more information:
http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/